# Service Based connection String that changes when on different machine

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have a Service based database and the default connection string is

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\James\OneDrive\Miller Veneers\Program\Current\HandHeld\SQLLibrary\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

which works. my problem is that when I go to change it to a dynamic so I can use this on a different computer it stops working.

I have tried

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" +
                   (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) +
                    @"\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security = True;");
```

and

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=/MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security = True;
```

thanks so much!

Comment: In config file you can't execute code. You can change it in codefile, eg in constructor.

Comment: how about `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your examples are a bit wrong.

Your second attempt goes wrong, I guess, because of the slash (/), instead of the backslash ().

Furthermore, I think getting your path might lead to incorrect results. If your code is located in a DLL which is located in the assembly cache, you get a path to the assembly cache, not the location of your application. Perhaps you should consider `GetEntryAssembly`.

Try to combine the dynamic path with the filename using `Path.Combine(...)`, something like this:

```
string connectionString = 
    @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=" +
    System.IO.Path.Combine(
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), 
        "MyDatabase.mdf") + 
    @";Integrated Security = True;"
```

Comment: for some reason I'm still not connecting it is returning "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=file:///C:/Users/James/OneDrive/Miller Veneers/Program/Current/HandHeld/Src/HandHeld/bin/Debug/SQLLibrary.DLL\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security = True;" as the string

Comment: My mistake. I removed the `GetDirectoryName`-part. I corrected it. Besided, if `CodeBase` does not work, perhaps try property `Location`.

Comment: You'll need to parse out the assembly name from the connection string - it is using "SQLLibrary.DLL" as part of it.

Comment: So I have finished the application, And published the app. now i am getting the same error only on the machine that it is to be deployed on. any ideas? only this time it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps you could write your connectionstring to a log file. Then you can see if the connectionstring is correct and verify if the database is at that given location.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving it in the config file, then change the username from the config when you want to change the DB path

Comment: I would like to use c# and build in constructor and set as property. as this is determined if they are connected to network or not.